# Using System Restore to change drive mount letters in windows 7

Tags: ssd, drive-letters

I am taking an existing desktop with a large spinning media and adding an SSD.  The spinning drive used to be c:.  I want to make the SSD c: and boot off it, and make the spinning drive D: - leaving the big document files on the spinning drive.

I used robocopy to move all the files in windows, programdata, etc from the spinning drive to the ssd.  I changed the boot records to the SSD is active and the system boots to it.

The problem is as soon as the OS loads off the SSD, it mounts the spinning drive as C and the SSD as D.  Things go south from there.

I cannot figure out how to change the letters that windows will mount drives to in system recovery.  I can use regedit and go to mounted devices - but that applies to the system recovery console itself.

I cannot figure out how to tell windows that when it boots, it should make the SSD drive C, and the spinning media drive D.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to figure this out.

I tried booting to safe mode and then using diskpart to change drive letters - that didn't work because diskpart won't let you change drive letters on the boot drive.

So what I found that did work was to boot to safe mode, and then use the registry editor to rename the entries under HKLM\SYSTEM\MountedDevices to change C: to D: and D: to C:.  The KB is here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/223188

Reboot and viola I had the drives in the right places.